# Why is Google blocking users from accessing their local file system in Chromium?

Tags: security, google, chrome

The question is based on [this issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=40787) in Chromium. It is marked as `Won't Fix`.

Do you see any reason to block a local html file from accessing another local html file located in the same folder?

Comment: On the contrary, I don't see any reason to allow it.

Comment: What about a local webapp or an extension? Is it forced to store all its data in a single long html file?

Comment: @Karpie I agree with your basic theory, but at the same time disagree with the realistic application.  There is a marked difference between academic and applied and, in this case, the suggested workarounds (ie., setting up another server, using security-disabling flags, etc.) seem worse than having an established model where "File in X directory has read permissions on other files in X directory".  Perfect?  No.  Better than kludgy alternatives?  Maybe?  The example case of "many applications are using HTML help docs" seems a reasonable real-world scenario.

Comment: If you want, you can try this over at http://security.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Karpie - you should explain why rather than just tossing in a throw-away like that. Not everyone understands security implications. Educating about what seems to be a fair question would be nice.

Comment: @Karpie: Just because you can't visualize it doesn't mean anyone wont need it. The world is full of so many unique problems.

Comment: @Vanuan: You can still include Javascript, CSS files and link to other local HTML files.

Comment: @sevenseacat, Ease of development

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but I didn't see this important fact mentioned anywhere:

Chrome allows you to add a folder on your file system as a local Web application.  Once you do that, files in that folder no longer need to be accessed through the `file:` protocol -- they become accessible through the `chrome-extension://` protocol, e.g., `chrome-extension://[app_id]/somefile.html`.  When accessing your files this way, the restrictions on local file access do not apply.

True, you need to write a small, three-line `manifest.json` file [[1](https://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html)] that specifies the name of your application, but if you want to use multiple local files as a local Web application, it makes some sense, security-wise, to require that you use Chrome's extension architecture to indicate clearly what folders on your hard drive should be accessed like Web applications.  That way, Chrome can assume that everything else on your hard drive is not a Web application, and lock down permissions on non-app HTML files that get loaded in the browser.  The addition of the `manifest.json` file adds only a few bytes to your folder, and it doesn't get in the way if you want to use your files in some other browser that does allow unfettered file access.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the real answer, but here's a good guess:

It's common to use File -> Save As... to save HTML to a file. Often users will save HTML files from different web sites to the same directory (perhaps named "Downloads"). Allowing one of these files to access the other (and possibly upload it somewhere) would be a privacy leak.

Since there are more users than developers and users are less security-aware on average, protecting users probably seems more important.

Even without this feature, it's still possible to create web applications that work offline. See: http://diveintohtml5.org/offline.html

Comment: I don't see how the last paragraph is relevant here though.'